# Updating a Table Based on Latest Record From Other Table

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.6

I have two tables as follows:

Table 1:

```
ID    Employee_ID     Date
1          1         1-1-2017
2          1         3-6-2017
3          2         4-5-2017
4          2         6-6-2017
5          3         5-8-2017
```

Table 2:

```
ID      Employee_ID    tbl1_ID
1           1           Null
2           2           Null
3           3           Null
```

No I want to get the ID of each employees latest record from Table 1 and set it in Table 2's tbl1_ID for those that tbl1_ID is null.

I wrote the below query for that but it takes a lot of time. Additionally in the first table I have 10 Million Records and the second one has 200K records.
Good to mention that PostgreSQL is tuned and the server holds good specs.

```
update table_2 tbl2 
   set tbl1_id = (select id 
                  from table_1 tbl1 
                  where tbl1.employee_id = tbl2.employee_id 
                  order by tbl1.date desc limit 1) 
where employee_id is not null 
and tbl1_id is null;
```

Comment: check if both tables have relationship and your table2 alias is wrong?

Comment: @krishKM it was a typing mistake and yes they do have relationship

Comment: have you tried to perform a select query and create temporary table form it? Temporary table would then be used to update your table2

Comment: I recommend you update the question with your table DDL (in particular column/datatypes and indexes), plus an explain analyze (ie, query plan) for the update; poor performance on a query like this is usually related to not finding a good/usable index for the join between the 2 tables

Comment: Thank you, This was solved with adding indexes and some query tuning